# HTTPS on Wordpress hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, .htaccess, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to force https over HTTP protocol for my website. I have managed to force the `http://example.com` => `https://example.com` and all blog post URLs.

However, when I try to access `https://example.com/wp-admin`, it says `example.com` redirected you too many times. `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

Please note that:

- My local development and AWS Elastic Beanstalk are connected to the same database.
- `localhost` and `localhost/wp-admin` works fine and can log in to admin panel successfully.
- I have setup an environment variable `WP_ENV` to determine if it is a local or production environment.

Here is my setup of my `wp-config.php` file.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';

/** HTTPS  */
if (getenv('WP_ENV') == 'production'){
    define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
    define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
    define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com');
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com');
}

if(getenv('WP_ENV') == 'development'){
    /* Http only.  */
    define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost');
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost');
}
```

And here is my .htacess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

<If "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
# For a site running on port 80 (http)
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}  ^80$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^wp-(admin|login|register)(.*) https://example.com/wp-$1$2 [L]
</If>

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}  ^80$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Is the SSL certificate installed on the EC2 instance running Wordpress? Or is the EC2 instance behind a load balancer or CDN or something that serves the SSL certificate?

Comment: @MarkB Elastic Beanstalk > Environment > Configuration > Load Balancer > Listener Port: 443 HTTPS, Instance Port: 80 HTTP. Certificate generated from AWS Certificate manager.

Comment: I did that just yesterday, did you put the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO line in the very beginning of your wp-config.php file?

Comment: Cross-site post on ServerFault by a different (unregistered) user: https://serverfault.com/questions/953027/https-on-wordpress-hosted-on-aws-elasticbean-stalk (?)

Comment: @bigandini Yes, I did put  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO line in the very beginning. I also tried to add before getenv('WP_ENV') but doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following instead in your `.htaccess` file:

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS (all requests)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Prevent additional filesystem check
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This assumes you are behind a load balancer/proxy that handles the SSL connection and the connection to your application server is actually over non-encrypted HTTP (which is why the standard checks against `HTTPS` or `SERVER_PORT` server variables appear to fail). The proxy (in front of your application server) sets the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header, informing the backend application server the nature of the connection to the client.

Change the `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) only when you are sure it's working OK in order to avoid caching issues.

With WordPress you should avoid editing the directives in the `# BEGIN WordPress` section as WordPress will try to overwrite this when it updates (unless you have taken additional steps to block this).