# Htaccess configuration for Https and www redirection for CDN delivered website?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, .htaccess, cpanel, amazon-cloudfront

**Ask - I am looking for https and www redirect !**

I have recently configured my laravel website to work on CDN, every thing worked fine as expected before implementing CDN with below htaccess code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -Indexes
  
  RewriteEngine On
  
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\\.php|resources|robots\\.txt)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**However, post implementing CDN it is throwing error - too many redirects, so I have kept like below for now, Atleast website is working.**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  Options -Indexes 
 
  RewriteEngine On 
 
 
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\\.php|resources|robots\\.txt) 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

**AWS CLoudfront:**
Source origin website -example(.com) (https) ||
CNAME Alias - www.example(.com) (https) ||
Behaviour: http to https

Could you please suggest what can I do with my htaccess rule. I need atleast below rules or else it will break my laravel website functionality.

```
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\\.php|resources|robots\\.txt) 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

please suggest a rule to add https and www redirection which should work with above lines.

**Also a generic question:** does redirect even works when served from CDN, am I missing any point to consider.

Would be a great help if this get fixed.

Comment: The "problem" is the HTTP to HTTPS redirection. See the linked questions. The non-www to www redirect is OK.

Comment: can you please suggest a way ? The links shared is not a precise solution, i tried implementing, still generating error.

Comment: Please edit your question with your complete `.htaccess` file with your attempted solution in-place. The first link is a "precise solution". I would literally copy the relevant part of my answer from that question and paste it here. I even modified my answer on that other question to explain what is happening.

Comment: I have updated my question, kindly check and let me know if it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

As per [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54600924/369434)/[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598059/https-on-wordpress-hosted-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk) I linked to initially, you likely need to check against the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header instead of the `HTTPS` server variable as the CDN behaves like a proxy, behind which your application server is connecting over plain HTTP.

The `X-Forwarded-Proto` header (a defacto-standard) is set by the proxy, informing the backend application server the protocol by which the user is connecting.

So, instead of the above, you would use the following instead:

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You need to clear all caches before testing (301s are cached persistently) and test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

Your existing non-www to www redirect (that follows) is "OK", although there is no need to capture the URL-path since it is not being used in the *substitition* string (you are using the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead).

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond $1 !^(index\\.php|resources|robots\\.txt)
> ```

This condition is not correct as written (it's basically doing nothing). The double-backslash matches a literal backslash, so this *negated* condition will always be successful. These should be single-backslash escapes, escaping the literal dot. For example:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for checking and answering this. As per your suggestion, I have come to above code. It is still giving too many redirect issue, can you pls check once again.

Comment: Pls check my answer, I was unable to put everything on comment